# Can jqGrid degrade gracefully?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I read a lot of good things about jqGrid on SO and would like to know if it is well suited for a project I am going to working on.

We are currently looking at either sticking with asp.net classic or moving to asp.net mvc (my preference after a year working with it).

I like that jqGrid works as a JQuery plugin or as a purchasable version for classic asp.net, giving us the option to change somewhere down the line if we choose to.

From my reading I see the JQuery version uses javascript to setup the grid.  Can this version be configured to degrade gracefully with javascript turned off?  Can we create the table using C# and then lay the JS over the top for extra functionality?

Are there any gotchas I should be aware of choosing jqGrid as our application's grid?

If anyone would like any clarifications please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct html table and then use tableToGrid (http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2h30t8wte.htm). In should work fine in every browser. You can also change tableToGrid script to match your needs, it is not hard.

Comment: @LukLed - I dont suppose you know how to tell tableToGrid NOT to mess with the contents of certain columns? I have an implementation whereby the `checkboxes` in the grid end up having their `name` changed after tableToGrid has done its thing (which messes with the resulting form post) - Thanks.