# Can jqGrid downgrade if javascript is didabled?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am currently evaluating grid components for our new portal project.  I came across the jqGrid which I find quite interesting. One requirement I have is that the portal should work with javascript switched off.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626125/can-jqgrid-degrade-gracefully) article on StackOverflow but it does not answer the question.  Does anyone can tell me how jqGrid is dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question which you referenced I could fine the following

> Can we create the table using C# and then lay the JS over the top for
>   extra functionality?

Is it what you plan? Do you want that your portal works without JavaScript and produce pure HTML tables which hold the data without any Ajax requests, but in case of the user do has JavaScript on you want to use JavaScript, jQuery and jqGrid?

In [the corresponding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626125/can-jqgrid-degrade-gracefully/1626165#1626165) it was suggested to use [tableToGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:table_to_jqgrid) function to convert the existing HTML table inclusive the contain to the jqGrid. It seems me the way which you can also follow. Why you are not satisfied with the answer?

To tell the trust I have no customers more where JavaScript is switched off. Do you want to develop the portal for some mobile devices or some other special endpoints which has no JavaScript? In my opinion JavaScript have to be on to be able to use Internet for the better productivity. So the portal which work without JavaScript will have the interface which is not up to date now. Either you have very special customer environment or the requirement seems me too hard.